# Calculation of refuelings (full and partly)

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

In one of my apps I need to calculate fuel consumption that takes into account complete refuelings and partly refuelings. My Android App is based on SQLite syntax and features.

I try to solve that puzzle in SQL and don't want to walk thru all rows to do this stuff programmatically.

Rows with FULL='N' should be left out in the result list but their values should be added to the next FULL='Y' row. At least that is my idea.

This is the DML (only required columns shown):

```
CREATE TABLE FUELINGS (
ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
MILEAGE INTEGER,
VOLUME DECIMAL(8, 2),
FULL CHAR(1));
```

Here's some input to this table:

```
INSERT INTO FUELINGS VALUES(1,22995,29.48,'Y');
INSERT INTO FUELINGS VALUES(2,23385,31.27,'Y');
INSERT INTO FUELINGS VALUES(3,23869,16.71,'N');
INSERT INTO FUELINGS VALUES(4,24065,33.18,'Y');
INSERT INTO FUELINGS VALUES(5,24485,30.59,'Y');
INSERT INTO FUELINGS VALUES(6,24956,33.78,'Y');
```

Ok, here comes the problem. This is the query I use:

```
SELECT T2.MILEAGE, 
       T2.VOLUME, 
       T2.FULL, 
       T2.PREVMILEAGE, 
       T2.PREVVOLUME, 
       T2.PREVFULL, 
       100 * T2.VOLUME / ( T2.MILEAGE - T2.PREVMILEAGE ) 
FROM   (SELECT T.MILEAGE, 
               T.VOLUME, 
               T.FULL, 
               T.PREVMILEAGE, 
               (SELECT VOLUME 
                FROM   FUELINGS 
                WHERE  MILEAGE = T.PREVMILEAGE 
                       AND MILEAGE IS NOT NULL 
                       AND MILEAGE > 0 
                       AND VOLUME IS NOT NULL 
                       AND VOLUME > 0) AS PREVVOLUME, 
               (SELECT FULL 
                FROM   FUELINGS 
                WHERE  MILEAGE = T.PREVMILEAGE 
                       AND MILEAGE IS NOT NULL 
                       AND MILEAGE > 0 
                       AND VOLUME IS NOT NULL 
                       AND VOLUME > 0) AS PREVFULL 
        FROM   (SELECT F.MILEAGE, 
                       F.VOLUME, 
                       F.FULL, 
                       (SELECT Max(MILEAGE) 
                        FROM   FUELINGS PREV 
                        WHERE  PREV.MILEAGE < F.MILEAGE 
                               AND MILEAGE IS NOT NULL 
                               AND MILEAGE > 0 
                               AND VOLUME IS NOT NULL 
                               AND VOLUME > 0) AS PREVMILEAGE 
                FROM   FUELINGS F 
                WHERE  MILEAGE IS NOT NULL 
                       AND MILEAGE > 0 
                       AND VOLUME IS NOT NULL 
                       AND VOLUME > 0) AS T 
        WHERE  PREVMILEAGE IS NOT NULL) AS T2 
ORDER  BY T2.MILEAGE;
```

This is the result:

```
T2.MILEAGE  T2.VOLUME   T2.FULL T2.PREVMILEAGE  T2.PREVVOLUME   T2.PREVFULL 100 * T2.VOLUME / (T2.MILEAGE - T2.PREVMILEAGE)
23385   31.27   Y   22995   29.48   Y   8.017948717948718
23869   16.71   N   23385   31.27   Y   3.4524793388429753
24065   33.18   Y   23869   16.71   N   16.928571428571427
24485   30.59   Y   24065   33.18   Y   7.283333333333333
24956   33.78   Y   24485   30.59   Y   7.171974522292993
```

16.92 is wrong because the refueling before that one was a partly refueling. I need to sum and calculate both rows. I am aware that there might be more than 1 partly refueling. But I don't have any clue how to build ranges of FULL='N' values, sum them up and add them to the following FULL='Y' value.

Can please somebody put me in the right direction. How can I make that right?

Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT/SOLUTION:**

```
SELECT T.MILEAGE,
       T.PREVMILEAGE,
       SUM(VOLUME),
       100 * SUM(VOLUME) / ( T.MILEAGE - T.PREVMILEAGE )
FROM   (SELECT F1.MILEAGE      AS MILEAGE,
               MAX(F2.MILEAGE) AS PREVMILEAGE
        FROM   FUELINGS F1
               LEFT OUTER JOIN FUELINGS F2
                 ON F1.MILEAGE > F2.MILEAGE
                    AND F2.FULL = 'Y'
                    AND F2.MILEAGE IS NOT NULL
                    AND F2.MILEAGE > 0
                    AND F2.VOLUME IS NOT NULL
                    AND F2.VOLUME > 0.0
        WHERE  F1.FULL = 'Y'
               AND F1.MILEAGE IS NOT NULL
               AND F1.MILEAGE > 0
               AND F1.VOLUME IS NOT NULL
               AND F1.VOLUME > 0.0
        GROUP  BY F1.MILEAGE) AS T,
       (SELECT VOLUME
        FROM   FUELINGS F3
        WHERE  F3.MILEAGE > T.PREVMILEAGE
               AND F3.MILEAGE <= T.MILEAGE)
GROUP  BY T.MILEAGE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original query would work if you had a table called FuelingsFull, which only contained complete information about full fuelings.  This can be summarized from Fueling.  The process would be simpler with window functions, but you don't have those in SQLite.

So, here is an idea on how to do this.  First, get the previous full id:

```
select f1.id, max(f2.full) as prevFullId
from fuelings f1 left outer join
     fuelings f2
     on f1.id > f2.id and
        f2.full = 0
group by f1.id
```

Now, you have a group of fuelings that all belong together.  The next query joins this back to the fuelings and then groups these together.

```
select fills.id, max(mileage) as mileage, sum(volume) as volume, count(*) as numFills
from fuelings f join
     (select f1.id, max(f2.full) as prevFullId
      from fuelings f1 left outer join
           fuelings f2
           on f1.id > f2.id and
              f2.full = 1
      group by f1.id
     ) fills
     on f.id > fills.prevFullId and f.id <= fills.id
  group by fills.id
```

With this as your FuelingFull, you original query should work.

Comment: I did not understand your idea immediately and a first test did not work as expected but the idea is really good. I will base my solution on your answer. Thanks a lot.